# Python Variable Attribute is None

Tags: python, tree

So I have a class for a Tree and class for nodes. And the init is:

```
def __init__(self, key=None, left=None, right=None, p=None):
    self.key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.p = p
```

Latter when I check if the right child is None I use:

```
 print(x.right == None)
```

This will always return False even if the right child is None.

To test this I have done:

```
>>> print(x.right)
None
>>> print(x.right == None)
False
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are accidentally setting `right` to the *string* 'None', and not the *value* **None** (with no quotes)?

For example:

```
>>> x.right = 'None'  # Oops - accidentally used quotes
>>> print(x.right == None)
False
>>> print(x.right == 'None')
True
```

Also, it's best to test for None with is, like:

```
>>> print(x.right is None)
```